# Return multiple files from Python ExecuteScript in NiFi

Tags: python-3.x, apache-nifi

I wrote a Python/Jython script to run in NiFi's `ExecuteScript` processor to parse my invalid JSON document. I wrote the script below based off of the script in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383529/using-sys-stdout-write-to-create-multiple-files-in-nifi) question and Matt Burgess's fantastic [cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-2/ta-p/249018), but it isn't returning multiple flow files. Instead, it returns the input flow file with the regex corrections applied, but only as just one file. What do I need to modify to return 1 flow file for each line in the loop?

**script**

```
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback
import re

# Define a subclass of StreamCallback for use in session.write()
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    # regex out invalid escapes -- WORKS
    text = re.sub(r"[(\\)]", "", text)
    # split out each line into a separate file -- DOES NOT WORK
    for t in text.splitlines():
        outputStream.write(t)
# end class
flowFile = session.get()
if(flowFile != None):
    try:
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Something went wrong', e)
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
# implicit return at the end
```

**json** -- goal is each line == one flow file

```
{"fruit":"apple", "vegetable":"celery", "location":{"country":"nor\\way", "city":"oslo"}, "color":"blue"}
{"fruit":"cherry", "vegetable":"kale", "location":{"country":"france", "city":"calais"}, "color":"green"}
{"fruit":"peach", "vegetable":"peas", "location":{"country":"united\\kingdom", "city":"london"}, "color":"yellow"}
```

**ETA** Added `session.create()` and removed original flow file with `session.remove(flowFile)` per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43107059/10145953) but NiFi says flowFile is not defined?

```
# imports not changed 
class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
        pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    text = re.sub(r"[(\\)]", "", text)
    flowfiles_list = []
    for t in text.splitlines():
        flowFile = session.create()
        if (flowFile != None):
            flowFile = session.write(flowfile, t)
            flowfiles_list.append(flowFile)
    for flow in flowfiles_list:
        session.transfer(flow, REL_SUCCESS)

originalFlowFile = session.get()
if(originalFlowFile != None):
    # NiFi says flowFile not defined
    originalFlowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback()) 
    session.remove(originalFlowFile)
```

Comment: from the same cookbook check session.create() examples
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-2/tac-p/249019#M5034

Comment: @daggett I attempted to incorporate `session.create()` (added to original post) but I got an error that the transfer relationship wasn't specified, though I thought I did that in `session.transfer(new_flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)`. Have I just not put code in the right positions, or am I still missing the mark?

Comment: you have to do something with all flow files - `transfer` or `remove`. probably you forgot to remove the original flow file...

Comment: @daggett modified op but I added `session.remove(flowFile)` but it's saying it's already marked for transfer elsewhere but I don't see where, outside of the except block

Comment: this is wrong `new_flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())` and I don't see in your code calling of `session.create()` in a loop

Comment: @daggett what is it that makes that wrong? I modified my code per https://stackoverflow.com/a/43107059/10145953 but it's giving me a new error.

Comment: `originalFlowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())` i believe it should be `originalFlowFile = session.write(originalFlowFile, PyStreamCallback()) `

Answer (score 0):

Return a list of flowFiles.
you have a exemple here : https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Split-one-Nifi-flow-file-into-Multiple-flow-file-based-on/m-p/203388/highlight/true#M165391

Comment: that looks like what I need, but I don't know Groovy so I'm not sure how to implement something similar in Python. Additionally, my actual JSONs are very large files and when run through other processors/attempts have caused memory errors--will loading it into a list cause a memory error, or will this be negated by the fact that it's in a stream?

Comment: do your code in python. just note how to work with session and flow files in example provided.